# Jquery. Как заменить td на th только в первой строке?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Как заменить все `<td>` и `<td>` первой строки на `<th>` и `</th>` соответственно, оставив нетронутым то, что находится внутри тегов (текст). Знаю, что есть такая штука как `.replace()`, но я не совсем понял, как ею моно воспользоваться в данной ситуации. Интересует готовое решение, которое позволяет изменить строкту типа

```
"<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>"
```

заменить на

```
"<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>"
```

Количество ячеек может быть произвольным.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решен.

Comment: Вы обратили внимание на  дурацкое, крайне неэффективное решение.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать подробности. Почему оно дурацкое и неэффективное?

Comment: Потому что each будет обходить каждый! td(не только в первом tr), в каждом цикле осуществлять ненужные манипуляции с DOM и операцию сравнения + если на странице будут две таблицы, то во второй(и всех последующих) таблице замена не произойдет, так как tr будут проиндексированы не относительно table, а относительно document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('td').each(function(){
if($(this).parent('tr').index() == 0)
{   $(this).replaceWith('<th>' +
$(this).text() + '</th>'); } });

});
```

Или другими способами: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-change-first-row-of-td-s-into-th-s

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('table tr:first td').each(function() {
     $(this).replaceWith('<th>' + $(this).html() + '</th>');
 });
```